# odoo record rules domain filter mrp.workcenter

Tags: security, filter, odoo, access-rules, record-rules

Hello I'd like restrict all users to just access the Work Center with ID = 1
I added a record rule for mrp.workcenter and added the domain filter [('id','=',1)]. But still I can see all the work centers...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given domain is correct and work fine.

You can see all the records from admin login. But if you can login from other user, suppose Manufacturing Manager than they can see only one record(I mean id=1).

By default, there are no any rules are apply to admin user. Please check it from other user.

Answer (score 1):

define access rules in security/ir.model.access.csv there you can set rights for create, edit, view and delete for specific groups

Comment: The question is about record Rules, not ACLs.